# Azure pipelines Deploy to kubernetes doesnt work with single quotes

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

It seems than the kubectl installed on agents doesnt allow using single quotes on pod name. it works when I dont use quotes.

```
2019-04-19T18:48:42.5271806Z ##[section]Starting: kubectl exec copy
2019-04-19T18:48:42.5279597Z ==============================================================================
2019-04-19T18:48:42.5279703Z Task         : Deploy to Kubernetes
2019-04-19T18:48:42.5279798Z Description  : Deploy, configure, update your Kubernetes cluster in Azure Container Service by running kubectl commands.
2019-04-19T18:48:42.5279903Z Version      : 1.150.8
2019-04-19T18:48:42.5279976Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-04-19T18:48:42.5280044Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851275)
2019-04-19T18:48:42.5280141Z ==============================================================================
2019-04-19T18:48:43.3986893Z Downloading: https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.13.3/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
2019-04-19T18:48:44.0419669Z Caching tool: kubectl 1.13.3 x64
2019-04-19T18:48:44.1159178Z Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: /opt/hostedtoolcache/kubectl/1.13.3/x64
2019-04-19T18:48:44.1454719Z [command]/opt/hostedtoolcache/kubectl/1.13.3/x64/kubectl exec -n namespace -it 'pod-name' -c container -- hostname
2019-04-19T18:48:44.3492926Z Error from server (NotFound): pods "'pod-name'" not found
2019-04-19T18:48:44.3584168Z ##[error]Error from server (NotFound): pods "'pod-name'" not found
2019-04-19T18:48:44.3598314Z ##[error]/opt/hostedtoolcache/kubectl/1.13.3/x64/kubectl failed with return code: 1
```

I would like to get dynamically pod name and I get it from previously "get pod output variable" but it sets single quotes when i use it in my exec args then it fails due to single quotes.